# Deployment isn't copying certain files over

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, build, nuget

I added [this NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/bootstrap-treeview/) to my MVC project written in C#. Everything works fine when I run my code locally.

But, when I deploy to my solution to my remote server and run it, it seems to be missing some of these scripts. For example, its missing `Scripts/bootstrap-treeview.js` and I get errors in the Chrome browser's debugger about it. The files are not being deployed onto the server at all because when I browse the remote server's disk I do not see them in the deployment location.

I checked the file's properties, its set to `Build Action: Content` and `Copy to Output Directory: Do not copy`. That's all that is set. I tried setting `Copy to Output Directory: Copy always` but that did not help fix the deployment to copy these files over. Other Stack questions eluded me to believe this should deploy because I've set `Build Action: Content`.

So the structure is as follows (if it helps in any way):

```
Project.csproj
   /Scripts
      /bootstrap-treeview.js <-- I want this file to deploy, but its not deploying.
```

What could the problem be?

Comment: What are you using to deploy the web site?

Comment: @AntonGogolev Right click project -> Deploy, remote deployment to server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we are using [bundling and minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification), the issue was that the bundle wasn't properly registered. It was also not rendered because of this (so there was no reference to it and it seems optimizations caused it to not deploy):

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/bootstrap-treeview.min.js"));
```

...and in my view (or layout view):

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```